# Exception in Java printf method

Tags: java, eclipse

This is the error I keep getting:

Total value of entire inventory is:$Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%.2f'

```
double total = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    total = total + products[i].getInventoryValue();
}

System.out.printf ("Total value of entire inventory is:$%.2f" + total);
System.out.println ();
Arrays.sort (products);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("Total value of entire inventory is:$%.2f" + total);
```

should be

```
System.out.printf("Total value of entire inventory is:$%.2f", total);
```

The first one concatenates the total with the string (to get a single longer string `"Total value of entire inventory is:$%.2f15.00"`) and then uses that as the format string (with no argument to replace the `%.2f`).

The second one actually lets `printf` format the string.